# problem with calculated measure

Tags: ssas

Hi i had a calculated dimension named employeeretirement based on the dateofbirth of the employee it will display the retirement year.My problem is when i changed the dateofbirths of the employees in  the database and processed the cube the changes are not reflecting the browser window.So to solve that im deleting the dimension and adding the from the table in dimension structure window so when i processed the cube and the changes are get displaying in the browser window.Is there any proper way to solve this issue,plz forward ur valuable answer to my mailid -naveen.vem007@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there are some definition problems in you question. Is the problem related to calculated dimension member or a  calculated measure? Although it is not clear, i think you are having problem because of not processing the related dimensions.

Processing the cube doesn't mean to process the dimensions. You should first process the dimension which you think has changed and then the cube.

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to recompile your sass?

Is this done with ruby?